# Correct Way to Code ASP.NET MVC HTML Helper That Requires an External JavaScript Library

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am getting ready to code a number of HTML helpers for UI elements in an ASP.NET MVC 3 project.  I expect many of the helpers to depend on code that is located in external javascript libraries.  These could be custom javascript libraries that I write, or they could reference 3rd party libraries like jQuery and jQueryUI.  For example, I might write HTML.RichM.DataPicker(...) that would require the page to have jQuery and jQueryUI referenced and some code executed in the document ready function.  Getting code into the document ready function is pretty straightforward I guess -- I could simply inject a new script block into the output with the contents of the function, even though that would mean I might have a page peppered with document ready functions all over.

The other part of this is making sure that the jQuery and jQuery UI libraries (in my example) are referenced and included.  Is there an "MVC way" to add the code references to the view page or the layout/master if they are not already there, or must I instruct users of my HTML helpers that they need to add references manually for any required javascript files?  Of course, I could just instruct them to include all possible external library references in the master or layout page, but that seems like overkill.  In ASP.NET Web Forms, for example, I might have used RegisterClientStartupScript or RegisterStartupScript to do this from my custom control.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to include the dependant scripts in the header, that's maybe not what you want to do, but I think it's the easiest way.

I suggest you using a tool like [SquishIt](http://www.codethinked.com/squishit-the-friendly-aspnet-javascript-and-css-squisher) to bundle your JS files together, that way, you will not have to load like 20 js files, it will be more efficient and cleaner.